# Azure Redis Cache vs Redis Cloud service on Azure

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to use it in a `.NET (webapi)` app & using `stackexchange.redis nuget` package.

Appreciate if someone please point me to appropriate resources for following -

1) Can I choose any of `Azure Redis cache or Redis cloud service` if I interface through `stackexchange.redis nuget`?

2) `Azure Redis Cache vs Redis Cloud` - differences & implications of choosing one over the other - if this info already available.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Redis Labs, the company providing Redis Cloud.

> 1) Can I choose any of Azure Redis cache or Redis cloud service if I interface through stackexchange.redis nuget?

Yes - both Azure Redis and Redis Cloud provide a Redis database that you can use with the StackEchange.Redis client from your app.

> 2) Azure Redis Cache vs Redis Cloud - differences & implications of choosing one over the other - if this info already available.

While both are essentially a hosted Redis service, there are several differences between them. Most notably, Azure Redis Cache is deeply integrated in the Azure platform so you have everything (management, metrics, etc...) accessible from your management portal. OTOH, Redis Cloud is cloud-agnostic (it is available on multiple clouds) and offers more features than any other Redis-as-a-Service service. I think that the fact that Redis Cloud is the **only** service that can scale infinitely and w/o downtime/migration is perhaps the strongest differentiator, but feel free to refer to this comparison table for a high level overview: https://redislabs.com/redis-comparison